# how to validate the app user login username and password

Tags: android, parse-platform

i am developing an android registration and login for users.

I am using Parse database to store the data, here am succesfully saving the username and password but i want to validate the user which he is alredy been signup.

Espically i wanted to compare the username and password of the user with the parse

How can i do this ?

Here is my Code :

```
public class ParseStarterProjectActivity extends Activity {
EditText ed1, ed2, ed3;
TextView tv1;
Button b1, b2;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Set up a new Parse user
            ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
            user.setUsername(ed1.getText().toString());
            user.setPassword(ed2.getText().toString());

            // Set up a progress dialog
            final ProgressDialog dlg = new ProgressDialog(
                    ParseStarterProjectActivity.this);
            dlg.setTitle("Please wait.");
            dlg.setMessage("Signing up.  Please wait.");
            dlg.show();

            user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    dlg.dismiss();
                    if (e != null) {
                        // Show the error message
                        Toast.makeText(ParseStarterProjectActivity.this,
                                e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        // Start an intent for the dispatch activity
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Signup Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
            query.whereEqualTo("Username", User);
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        // The query was successful.
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                ParseStarterProjectActivity.this,
                                Sub1.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        // Something went wrong.
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    });
}
}
```

Comment: already sign up is check with the server dude give pass nd useremail ans get the response coz if u chk with data base and if any one if delete chache from setting then nothing wil be in database

Answer (score 2):

When signing up an already registered user, instead of using a ParseQuery, use

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground("username", "password", new LogInCallback(){
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
        if (user != null && e == null){
            //login was successful
        }
    }
});
```

The `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` static method will always then give you the currently logged in user, or `null` if logged out.

I also recommend reading through the Parse documentation on users at https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#users